# Implement Generic Get<T> for MemoryCache (or any Cache)

Tags: c#, generics, caching, type-conversion, memorycache

I'm trying to write a **"simple"** Generic `Get<T>`; extension for 
`System.Runtime.MemoryCache`.

Why "simple" ? Because generally I know object's real type before caching it, so when I retrieve it from cache, I'm not going to convert it in unpredictable ways.

For example: if boolean "true" value is stored in cache with cacheKey "id", so

```
Get<string>("id") == "true";
Get<int>("id") == 1; // any result > 0 is okay
Get<SomeUnpredictableType> == null; // just ignore these trouble conversions
```

Here's my incomplete implemention:

```
public static T DoGet<T>(this MemoryCache cache, string key) {
    object value = cache.Get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        return default(T);
    }
    if (value is T) {
        return (T)value;
    }

    // TODO: (I'm not sure if following logic is okay or not)
    // 1. if T and value are both numeric type (e.g. long => double), how to code it?
    // 2. if T is string, call something like Convert.ToString()

    Type t = typeof(T);
    t = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) ?? t);
    if (typeof(IConvertible).IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType())) {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

===================================

Update (04/11/2016):

For those nice suggestions given, I implement my first version of Get<T>

```
public class MemCache {
    private class LazyObject<T> : Lazy<T> {
        public LazyObject(Func<T> valueFactory) : base(valueFactory) { }
        public LazyObject(Func<T> valueFactory, LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) : base(valueFactory, mode) { }
    }

    private static T CastValue<T>(object value) {
        if (value == null || value is DBNull) {
            return default(T);
        }
        Type valType = value.GetType();
        if (valType.IsGenericType && valType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(LazyObject<>)) {
            return CastValue<T>(valType.GetProperty("Value").GetValue(value));
        }
        if (value is T) {
            return (T)value;
        }
        Type t = typeof(T);
        t = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) ?? t);
        if (typeof(IConvertible).IsAssignableFrom(t) && typeof(IConvertible).IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType())) {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    private MemoryCache m_cache;

    public T Get<T>(string key) {
        return CastValue<T>(m_cache.Get(key));
    }

    public void Set<T>(string key, T value, CacheDependency dependency) {
        m_cache.Set(key, value, dependency.AsCacheItemPolicy());
    }

    public T GetOrAdd<T>(string key, Func<T> fnValueFactory, CacheDependency dependency) {
        LazyObject<T> noo = new LazyObject<T>(fnValueFactory, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
        LazyObject<T> old = m_cache.AddOrGetExisting(key, noo, dependency.AsCacheItemPolicy()) as LazyObject<T>;
        try {
            return CastValue<T>((old ?? noo).Value);
        } catch {
            m_cache.Remove(key);
            throw;
        }
    }

    /* Remove/Trim ... */
}
```

Comment: You could use (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T)) but this would be only a part of your very generic method.

Comment: Thanks, I added to my sample code. I'm still not sure if there're some conditions I missed in TODO section.

Comment: Write unit-tests, add all the cases you want it to handle.

Comment: I wouldn't simply return `default(T)` with "trouble conversions" - you may want to have a `TryGet`, `GetOrDefault` that don't, and a `Get` that does throw an exception when conversion fails - you could also contstraint that `T` must be `IConvertible`, if you don't plan on adding other types.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Besides, I am doing some research on making the method functional for Lazy<T> type. That is: cache.DoGet<int> to retrieve an integer value after cache.Set(Lazy<long>) for the same item.

Comment: May be you can add some logic that will make your code more scalable and allow other coders to contribute to your code. For example you can add some interfaces or use pattern 'strategy' that will define each convertion logic separately. That will allow me for example to extend your logic with my custom class `MyClass` just by implementing the interface

Comment: Why do you want to support convertion of value to other numeric types? I would drop this. Just cast the value to `T` and you are done and it is all stable and transparent as it should be.

Comment: You are right. My implemention is for those "lazy" users who want less coding on converted result :P Actually use something like (double)cacheItem out of cache class is a much more efficient way. @StefanSteinegger

Comment: These implicit conversions are really nasty API design. This is like JavaScript converting strings to ints for you. All of the nullable logic can be deleted as well because `null is bool?` is true. Casts have intrinsic nullable support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The essential work is to write a CastValue<T> to convert any object to desired type. And it doesn't have to handle very complicate condition because object types in cache is predictable for the programmer. And here's my version.

```
public static T CastValue<T>(object value) {
    if (value == null || value is DBNull) {
        return default(T);
    }
    if (value is T) {
        return (T)value;
    }
    Type t = typeof(T);
    t = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) ?? t);
    if (typeof(IConvertible).IsAssignableFrom(t) && typeof(IConvertible).IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType())) {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Proposal:

```
public static T DoGet<T>(this MemoryCache cache, string key) 
{
    object value = cache.Get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        return default(T);
    }
    // support for nullables. Do not waste performance with 
    // type conversions if it is not a nullable.
    var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
    if (underlyingType != null)
    {
        value = Convert.ChangeType(value, underlyingType);
    }
    return (T)value;
}
```

Usage (supposed you have an id of type `int` in the cache):

```
int id = Get<int>("id"); 
int? mayBeId = Get<int?>("id");
string idAsString = Get<int?>("id")?.ToString();
double idAsDouble = (double)Get<int>("id");
```

I haven't test it.

Comment: It looks like some conditions are missing, as you assume it can always return (T)value. I tested and got "Specified cast is not valid" exception.

Comment: What did you add to the cache, what did you trying to read from it?

Comment: numbers, texts, or any heavy loaded objects (entities) @StefanSteinegger

Comment: So what does it try to cast?

Comment: Here is the logic: if it is numeric, it can be converted from one type to another(int/double/long...), any flat values can be converted to string, boolean types can be converted to string or int, other objects just remain their own types and will be converted explicitly

Comment: I just propose to not do this. I would always explicitly convert or cast. It is quite a bit of work to do what you want and will always be a bit magic, but should be reliable. I would support implicit casting to nullables. Note: the type conversion you call with (type)-cast is quite complex and is generated by the compiler, you don't have access to it at runtime.

Comment: The purpose of why I'm insisting on implement this generic method is that I was attracted by ExecuteScalar<T> implemention of "Dapper", it shows some magic that can converts any DB result to your desired type(e.g varchar => int). So does those magics apply to Cache ? That's what I think.